# Apacite displaying different styles in different documents

Tags: apa-style, apacite

I have a document that displays properly the APA citations and that does not do that. The document that does display properly:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{PlenborgKold,
    author =       "Thomas Plenborg and Jens Knudsen and Simon Kold",
    title =        "Stick to the Fundamentals and Discover your Peers",
    journal =      "Financial Analysts Journal",
    volume =       "73",
    number =       "3",
    pages =        "85--105",
    year =         "2017",
}

@article{BhojrajLee2003,
    author =       "Sanjeev Bhojraj and Charles M. C. Lee",
    title =        "What's My Line? A Comparison of Industry Classification Schemes for Capital Market Research",
    journal =      "Journal of Accounting Research",
    volume =       "41",
    number =       "5",
    pages =        "745--774",
    year =         "2003",
}

@article{SBP2016,
    author =       "Charles M.C. Lee and Paul Ma and Charles C.Y. Wang",
    title =        "The Search for Peer Firms: When Do Crowds Provide Wisdom?",
    journal =      "Harvard Business School Accounting \& Management Unit Working Paper, Stanford University Graduate School of Business Research Paper and Rock Center for Corporate Governance at Stanford University Working Paper",
    number =       "15-032, 14-46, 198",
    year =         "2016",
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\noindent ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CITE: \cite{SBP2016}

\noindent ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CITET: \citet{SBP2016}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

When I use `\citet{SBP2016}` it displays:

[image]

However, in the other document, when I use `\citet{SBP2016}` it displays:

[image]

As you can see, in the second image, the initials of the author is included. I do not want that to happen. I would like to include the other document, but it is too big and complex to post it. I used the same `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and the `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. I also use `\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}`, but even after removing it, the problem persisted. And I do not use other citing packages in my preamble. Does anyone have an idea what might cause this? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be more than enough. Thank you!

Comment: This is how the APA style deals with different authors with the same last name. I suspect you have two Lee papers in the second paper, and so APA uses initials to distinguish them. If they are supposed to be the same Lee, then you need to make sure that their `.bib` file entries are exactly the same, otherwise the problem will persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in one of the entries, the `author` field is given as

```
    author = "Charles M.C. Lee and Paul Ma and Charles C.Y. Wang",
```

By the (admittedly rather strict) syntax rules of the `apacite` bibliography style, this isn't the same as either

```
    author = "Charles M. C. Lee and Paul Ma and Charles C. Y. Wang",
```

or

```
    author = "Charles M. Lee and Paul Ma and Charles C. Wang",
```

To eliminate any chance for ambiguity, the `apacite` package is set up to show the given name initials in the citation call-outs in such cases.

The fix? Make sure that you don't have these minor-looking, though anything but innocuous, syntax issues in your bib file.

Which version is best? I go with `Charles M. C. Lee`, i.e., I'd make sure that there's a space between `M.` and `C.`.